# How do I dump a remote MySQL database to my local machine using java?

Tags: java, mysql, database, raspberry-pi, lamp

I'm attempting to perform a backup of my database from my java program. The database is located on my raspberry pi , and I'm accessing it from my laptop.
Every attempt to do this has led to the following error, what file exactly is the error referring to, is it in my raspberry pi, and if yes, how do I locate it?

All suggestions are welcome.

Here's my code:

```
void backUpDatabase(){

    ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override
            public void run() {
            try {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mysqldump -h " + connURL +" -u <user> -p <password> <databaseName>"
                                        + "> <The/local/path/for/the/backup> ");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(LogInScreenController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
                System.out.println("Run");
        }
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
}
```

Error Message:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mysqldump": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)
at login.LogInScreenController$4.run(LogInScreenController.java:544)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at
```

Comment: your program did not find `mysqldump` executable..try to add absolute path of it..like `\"C:/Program Files/MySQL/bin/mysqldump\" -h....`

Comment: I know,obviously thats what the error says, but how do I locate it on the raspberry pi? The database is on a remote raspberry pi

Answer (score 0):

Install the `mysql clients` utility on your laptop. Once it is installed, then execute your java program/class.

You should have MySQL clients on a client system from which you are taking the backup.

UPDATE:

When you have to execute the command with arguments, please use this [exec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[])) Api rather than [exec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)) Api.

Comment: Btw, you do not need to write a java program to take the backup. Once you have the client utility you can use the same command from your command/shell window.

Comment: Thanks @ Rishikesh Darandale  .. Let me try that, I have to use java because I want to add the functionality to a java program

Comment: I think I already have mysql clients utility installed because I can access the database from the command prompt

Comment: Please try to add the absolute path of the utility command in your java program.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for your time. Let me try again.

Comment: Using the path still says file not found, I have located the file path in my system variables and I can use mysqldump, and mysql client just by typing them on my command prompt, even without typing the file path. But the commands are not working on the Java runtime.exec

Comment: Can you please try it as below? `String[] command = { "mysqldump", "-h"+hostname, "-u"+username, "-p" + password, "<DATABASE_NAME>", "<FILE_PATH_TO_STORE>" };` Use this `command` variable in `exec` method.

Comment: @dashing_rowland, Great to know that.